# Why use the __all__ variable in Python?

Tags: python

I know what it does, how it works and all, but *why* might we ever want to use it?

I mean if a programmer wanted to import the objects from a module, he could then just use the simple

```
import <module>
```

syntax. It's not like the all variable is hiding anything, right?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from <module> import *` and `help(<module>)` both use the `__all__` attribute of a module to limit what is imported or documented.

Note that `from <module> import *` is generally considered bad practice unless you are building a central API for a package with the implementation dispersed over various contained modules.

Comment: OK, I am just  a novice Python programmer, so I didn't get any of the last sentence, but again, how is it *limiting* anything? You can still get the objects you want without any trouble.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi: It is not intended to limit what is accessible. It is only limiting what automated tools will use. `from <module> import *` would import **all** global names otherwise, including other modules imported into `<module>`. This is usually not what you want.

Comment: OK, I got it now. Thanks. :)